# Invalid CSS Susy 1.0.9

Tags: terminal, susy-compass, susy-sass

I got this invalid code. I use it with grunt. I try some versions in combination, still failed.

Thanks for your help

Ogni

#### Terminal

```
error sass/style.scss (Line 13 of sass/susy/language/susyone/_grid.scss: 
Invalid CSS after "...x-sizing: true ": expected "}", was "!global;")
```

### My Settings

#### .scss

```
@import "susyone";
```

...

#### Gemfile

```
gem "sass", "~>3.2.19"
gem "compass", "~>0.12.6"
gem "susy", "~>1.0.9"
```

#### config.rb

```
require "susy"
 # Require any additional compass plugins here.

 # Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "."
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

#### Gruntfile.js

```
...
// Compass
compass: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      config: 'config.rb'
    }
  }
},
...
```